# Estimating the sign of an integral

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to show that the  expression below
$$c|t|^{\alpha} \bigg( \int \limits_{|u| < |t|} \frac{e^{iu} -1 -iu}{|u|^{1 + \alpha}} \mbox{d}u + \int \limits_{|u| \ge |t|} \frac{e^{iu} -1}{|u|^{1 + \alpha}} \mbox{d}u \bigg) $$
can be rewritten as
$$-b |t|^{\alpha}$$
for some $b > 0$.

It's easy to show that both integrals converge. However there are two issues I don't know how to deal with. The first one is connected to the sign of the integral - how can it be shown that both the sum of integrals is negative? The second issue is linked to $|t|$ in the integration limits. Is that a problem? I suppose that the sum of the integrals in brackets should be a negative constant.

Comment: You assume that $a=0$, but I see no further mention of any $a$. Also, I see a lot of irrelevant information; you want to show that there exists some $b>0$ such that
$$c\int \limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{itx} -1 - itx \mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(x)}{|x|^{1+\alpha}} \mbox{d}x=-b|t|^{\alpha}+2\pi ki,$$
for some $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: @Servaes you're right! I've made a typo. Now it's fixed. And yes - basically I would like to show what you wrote in your comment

Comment: @Servaes there was no $2 \pi ki$ mentioned in the content of the task

Comment: Consider what it means for the two powers of $e$ to be equal. Though for such $b$ and $k$ to exist for every $c>0$, you must clearly have $k=0$.

Comment: @Servaes I've made some edits. I think now my post is much better and contains less irrelevant information

Comment: I agree. I guess you can omit the term $|t|^{\alpha}$ from both expressions as the case $t=0$ poses no restrictions on $b$. Also, your tag suggests that $c$, $u$, $t$ and $\alpha$ are real variables, but I would suggest you make their domains explicit in the body of the question. For example, you really need that $c>0$ to get that $b<0$.